# How to add a View from Dialog to MainActivity

Tags: android, layout, view, android-alertdialog

I have a problem,
I am new to android, my problem is:

I have main activity, where i have a button which opens a new alert dialog, here is example of my dialog:

http://pastebin.com/n1NDsbQp

and what I want to do is by clicking "SET" button on the Dialog, add a new View like EditText to my MainActivity to LinearLayout called: "reminder_layout"

I have no idea how to do this...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perform the action in onButtonClickListiner of Dialog or onPositveButton (What ever you defined in your code).

Get the Reference of you Declared LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.lineralayout);
```

Create your View here

```
EditText valueTv = new EditText(this);
    valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
    valueTV.setId(5);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Add to your layout

```
layout.addView(valueTV);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for answer but I think this won't work...The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type RemindDialog (my class name)

Comment: May I know what type of issues you are facing while doing the same.

Comment: When I declare layer inside DialogFragment class ( LinearLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.lineralayout); ) i get this error: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type RemindDialog

Comment: try to initate LinearLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.lineralayout); in oncreate.

Comment: Ok, this solution has worked, but I also created a static field of EditText in my MainActivity.java, and only gave a reference to this object in onClick method. But how to create a few EditText view, notice that I may click few times on SET button, and beacause of that i want to create a few EditText views.